# How to create get 3 values in description of each unique value in client column

Tags: mysql, sql

**Example of database**

| client | descr |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | pip |
| 1 | pop |
| 1 | pap |
| 1 | pep |
| 1 | ptp |
| 1 | prp |
| 1 | pqp |
| 1 | pwp |
| 1 | pyp |
| 1 | pup |
| 1 | ppp |
| 2 | pfp |
| 2 | pgp |
| 2 | php |
| 3 | psp |
| 3 | pdp |
| 3 | pfp |
| 4 | pgp |
| 4 | php |
| 4 | pvp |

I tried to do with `where` and `limit` clauses, but it makes answer like this

| client | descr |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | pip |
| 1 | pop |
| 1 | pap |

but i need

| client | descr |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | pip |
| 2 | pfp |
| 3 | psp |

considering of `LIMIT` value

Comment: There's no '4' in your result?!?!?!?!

Comment: it was just example, but thx

Comment: You're going to want to use GROUP BY and you'll need to choose the appropriate aggregation function for your descr field. 

It would help if you included: 
1. The SQL you tried (I can guess from your post but its better not to guess)
2. More information on how the three rows in "what you need" are determined. Like if you were explaining to a human how to pick the three client/description pairs what would you say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` to identify one row per client. For example:

```
select client, descr
from (
  select *, row_number() over(partition by client order by descr) from t
) x
where rn = 1
```

Comment: But it works only if we want to get per 1 client, how to get, f.e. 3 rows per client

Comment: If you want 3 rows per client change the predicate in the last line to: `rn <= 3`.